Linker and Memory map for shared memory in autosar embedded environment
I am trying to understand the Autosar memory map concept. I have two core micro controller which will send some datas to each other. So I have a shared memory for IPC communication. In my project, I can able to see some of the area they have reserved for the shared memory.
Linker file:
MEMORY {
 CORE_SHARED_RAM  : org = 0x200C1020, len = 0x00000FA0
}

 GROUP : {
    __CORE_SHARED_RAM_START = .;
    .CoreIpcRAM_noinit ALIGN(4): { *(.CoreIpcRAM_noinit) }
    __CORE_SHARED_RAM_END = .;
  } > CORE_SHARED_RAM

MemMap.h
#ifdef M1_START_SEC_CONST_UNSPECIFIED
   #undef M1_START_SEC_CONST_UNSPECIFIED
   #undef MEMMAP_ERROR 
   #pragma section DATA  ""  "CoreIpcRAM_noinit"
   #pragma section SDATA ""  "CoreIpcRAM_noinit"
#endif

#ifdef M2_START_SEC_IPC_MEMORY_VAR_NOINIT_32BIT
   #undef M2_START_SEC_IPC_MEMORY_VAR_NOINIT_32BIT
   #undef MEMMAP_ERROR 
   #pragma section DATA "" ".CoreIpcRAM_noinit"
   #pragma use_section DATA m2_Ipc_Memory
#endif

I would like to understand what is this code exactly do in the memory.

What is MEMORY, GROUP tag in the linker file and what is the purpose of *(.CoreIpcRAM_noinit) variable?

In the Memap file, why CoreIpcRAM_noinit defined twice?
#pragma section DATA  ""  "CoreIpcRAM_noinit"
#pragma section SDATA ""  "CoreIpcRAM_noinit"

In the memmap file, why CoreIpcRAM_noinit used in the both M1_START_SEC_CONST_UNSPECIFIED and M2_START_SEC_IPC_MEMORY_VAR_NOINIT_32BIT definitions?

What is the use of #pragma use_section DATA m2_Ipc_Memory command?



You did look up the linker's documentation for the linker script tags, didn't you? And you did look up your compiler's documentation for the pragmas, didn't you? Please [edit] your question and extend what you understood, and why these documentations did not help you. BTW, please add details including the version of the tools you use.

refer to GNU LD Linker, and other documentations

What is MEMORY, GROUP tag in the linker file and what is the purpose of *(.CoreIpcRAM_noinit) variable ?

MEMORY section defines the memory regions available on the microcontroller. Each memory region has a starting address (org) and length (len).
GROUP sections or variables that should be placed in a specific memory region.
.CoreIpcRAM_noinit ALIGN(4) section contains variables that should be placed in the CORE_SHARED_RAM and aligned to 4 bytes.

In the Memap file, why CoreIpcRAM_noinit defined twice ?

This is the way memory sections are handled for different data types or use cases in embedded systems.

In the memmap file, why CoreIpcRAM_noinit used in the both M1_START_SEC_CONST_UNSPECIFIED and M2_START_SEC_IPC_MEMORY_VAR_NOINIT_32BIT definitions ?

Both cores are likely sharing data via inter-processor communication (IPC) and need access to the same region of memory.

What is the use of #pragma use_section DATA m2_Ipc_Memory command ?

It tells the compiler to place all subsequent variable declarations in a section named m2_Ipc_Memory.
